# XamDataGrid how to add right mouse click action in field? (Infragistics)

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am using `XamDataGrid` from *Infragistics*, I want to add something like `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` of the `TextBox` into `XamDataGrid` field.

I want to open file dialog when the right mouse button is clicked on the cell and save related URL in it.

Here is my **XAML**

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid RenderTransformOrigin="0.146,-3.629" DataSource="{Binding Path=Wavelets}" GroupByAreaLocation="None">
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False"
                                  AutoFitMode="Always" 
                                  AddNewRecordLocation="OnTopFixed"
                                  AllowAddNew="True" />
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        <igDP:FieldLayout>
            <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                <igDP:Field  Name="AngleFile" Label="Anglestack file"/>
                <igDP:Field Name="WaveletFile" Label="Wavelet file "/>
                <igDP:Field Name="DataField" Label="Data file"/>                       
            </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
        </igDP:FieldLayout>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

Comment: Use a TemplateField with an EditTemplate? https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/xamdatagrid-configuring-template-field

Comment: Yup, it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `Field` with a `TemplateField` and define an `EditTemplate` with a `TextBox` as suggested in the [official documentation](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/xamdatagrid-configuring-template-field).